# Display recent comments with gravatar and excerpts?

Tags: comments

I couldn't seem to find a plugin with both functionality so I created mine(not a plugin) thru the help of my old friend google. My code works but there's a small glitch, the title of the posts are the same for all recent comments.

```
$comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
<ul> <?php 
foreach ($comments as $comment) { 
    $post_obj = get_post($comment->post_id); 
    $title = $post_obj->post_title; ?>
    <li><?php
        echo get_avatar( $comment, '42' );
        echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?>&nbsp;<?php
        echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 35 ); ?><br />
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->post_id); ?>" rel="external nofollow" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"> <?php echo $title; ?> </a> 
    </li>
<?php }  ?>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Here's the current code. Edited according to Ambitious Amoeba.

```
$comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
    <li><?php
        $title = get_the_title($comment->post_ID);
        echo get_avatar( $comment, '42' );
        echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author);
        ?>&nbsp;<?php
        echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 35 ); ?>
        <br /><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->post_ID); ?>" rel="external nofollow" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"> <?php echo $title; ?> </a>
    </li>
<?php }  ?>
```

Still getting the same result. All with the same title. Though it changes the post title according what is currently viewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$comment->comment_post_ID` instead of `$comment->post_id`.

Also you don't need get_post(...). Just use [get_the_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead of your `$post_obj` and related code...

Comment: I am still getting the same result. All with the same title. Though it changes the post title according what is currently viewed. I updated the code..

Comment: I still see the same code there, at least in your updated question. Read my answer again, especially the 1st line

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `wp_reset_query()`; at the bottom of your single post/page? I'm assuming that the previous query is flowing over into your widget query and that the reset mentioned above is missing from the single template.

Cheers

Noel

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work :-(

Comment: Hmmm.. and right before your widget? (i.e. at the top of the code above)

Comment: Yah. I am using Thematic and just found out it has its own Recent comments widget but without gravatar. I am guessing it's causing conflicts.

Comment: Ahh yes, that would explain things. Not familiar with Thematic unfortunately :/